# Buefy table not rendering in nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I use nuxt and buefy out of the box and i only want to display a table with dummy data. But nothing gets rendered. I copied the code from Buefy Documentation.

```
//TableComponent
<template>
  <b-table :data="tableData" :columns="columns" />
</template>


<script>
    export default {
   data() {
    return {
        tableData: [
            {
                . . .
            }
        ],
        columns: [
            {
            ...
                      }
        ]
    }
   }
   }
</script>

//Parent Component
 <div>
<TableComponent />
 <div>
```

Comment: Have you registered your `TableComponent` in components in your parent component? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Yes, eslint does not allow build if the component is not properly registered  anyway! In console i get nothing...!

Comment: If you said you correctly registered your `TableComponent`, your code looks good. Improve your question with the full parent component code, and with nuxt.config.js or something else...